# Conditonals nested in groups

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

I am working with some data like this:

```
ID    Count  Report  Rank   
X-01   1      4.2     2 
X-01   2      2.7     1     
X-01   3      5.8     3 
X-01   4      14      5 
X-01   5      9.2     4
X-02   1      6.8     2 
X-02   2      17      4     
X-02   3      13      3 
X-02   4      22.7    5 
X-02   5      4       1
```

Count refers to when the sensor was triggered, Report is the value, Rank is the ranking within Report.

I am interested in 6 variables from this:

```
If Count = 1 and Rank = 1 then Report
If Count = 1 and Rank = 2 then Report
If Count > 1 and Rank = 1 or 2, then -1
If Count = 1 and Rank = 3:5, -Report
If Count >= 2 and Rank = 3:10, 1
If Rank > 5 (there are multiple rows to each ID), 0
```

I have tried if (x) {} else if () {} etc and ifelse() with multiple nests but am getting a lot of red text back!

```
Larger object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

is frequent.

So far the only solution I've found is to calculate each one in a column through 'ifelse' and then add up the rows in a new column which is time consuming and not elegant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function that specifies the output given each combination of inputs.

```
f1 <- function(count, rank, report){

  # in case of missing count or rank data:
  if (is.na(count) | is.na(rank)) return(NA)
  if (count==1 & rank %in% 1:2) return(report)
  if (count > 1 & rank %in% 1:2) return(-1)
  if (count==1 & rank %in% 3:5) return(-report)
  if (count >= 2 & rank %in% 3:10) return(1)
  if (rank > 5) return(0)
  return(NA)
}
```

Next you can use `mapply` to apply this function to your data.frame.

```
mapply(f1, count=d$Count, rank=d$Rank, report=d$Report)
[1]  4.2 -1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  6.8  1.0  1.0  1.0 -1.0
```

**Edit:** I updated the function so that it returns `NA` if some of the input variables are `NA`.

Given this dataset:

```
d <- read.table(text='ID    Count  Report  Rank   
                      X-01   1      4.2     2 
                      X-01   2      2.7     1     
                      X-01   3      5.8     3 
                      X-01  NA      4       2
                      X-01   2      5.5     NA
                      X-01   4      14      5 
                      X-01   5      9.2     4
                      X-02   1      6.8     2 
                      X-02   2      17      4     
                      X-02   3      13      3 
                      X-02   4      22.7    5 
                      X-02   5      4       1', header=T)
```

I get this output:

```
mapply(f1, count=d$Count, rank=d$Rank, report=d$Report)
[1]  4.2 -1.0  1.0   NA   NA  1.0  1.0  6.8  1.0  1.0  1.0 -1.0
```

Comment: I've tried this and I get `Error in if (count == 1 & rank %in% 3:5) return(-report) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` and then the Console reports `Browse[1] >` which I clear with `Q`, return.

Comment: @Foothill_trudger Do you per chance have `NA` data in your full dataset then? Given your example dataset I assumed there was no missing data.

Comment: Yes, there are the occasional NA data and you've nailed it so thank you!